# PgPool-II can't find the servers where the databases live (even though the PgPool is on a db server)

Tags: high-availability, postgresql-13, pgpool

`PgPool-II 4.3.3` `Postgresql 13.9` `RHEL 8.6`

Postgresql is installed on FOOBARa and FOOBARb, and data is successfully being stream replicated from `a` to `b`.

Then I installed PgPool-II on `a`, and configured the two backend_host configuration variables to point to the two db servers.

However, pgpool throws `getaddrinfo() failed with error "Name or service not known"` on **both** it's own node and the remote node, even though the two hostname commands (and ssh) work perfectly.

What am I misunderstanding?

```
$ grep backend_hostname pgpool.conf
backend_hostname0 = 'FOOBARa'
backend_hostname1 = 'FOOBARb'

$ hostname
FOOBARa

$ ssh -q FOOBARb hostname
FOOBARb

2023-01-25 12:07:45.156: child pid 786204: DEBUG:  initializing backend status
2023-01-25 12:07:45.157: main pid 786138: WARNING:  failed to connect to PostgreSQL server, getaddrinfo() failed with error "Name or service not known"
2023-01-25 12:07:45.157: main pid 786138: LOG:  find_primary_node: make_persistent_db_connection_noerror failed on node 0
2023-01-25 12:07:45.165: main pid 786138: DEBUG:  authenticate kind = 10
2023-01-25 12:07:45.172: main pid 786138: LOG:  find_primary_node: make_persistent_db_connection_noerror failed on node 1
2023-01-25 12:07:45.172: main pid 786138: DEBUG:  pool_acquire_follow_primary_lock: lock was not held by anyone
2023-01-25 12:07:45.172: main pid 786138: DEBUG:  pool_acquire_follow_primary_lock: succeeded in acquiring lock
2023-01-25 12:07:45.172: main pid 786138: DEBUG:  verify_backend_node_status: there's no primary node
2023-01-25 12:07:45.172: main pid 786138: DEBUG:  pool_release_follow_primary_lock called
```